# Do I need MX records for a subdomian in Google Workspace if they subdomain will only be allowed to email other domains within our workspace?

Tags: mx-record, g-suite

I'm one of those IT guys who knows just enough to get in trouble, but not enough to be able to acnswer what I feel like is a simple question. I work with a non-profit in California, and we currently use Google Workspace for email. We currently have our primary domain, which I'll call primarydomain.org. We are looking to set up our volunteers with a log-in in Google so they can access shared calendars and drives among a few other resources, but we don't want them having a true email address they can send email to and recieve email from the outside world. My thought was to add in a subdomain, volunteers.primarydomain.org, and create a new Orgainizational Unit within Google that has gmail disabled, except for emailing other users within our Workspace. The issue I'm running into is when I create the new domain, it wants me to add a new MX record for the sub-domain. Normally I would just add the record, but the person who used to be in charge of things like this moved our DNS records to Wix, and they don't allow MX records for subdomains unless you are on a a high enough plan. I have a couple questions, but they are all related to this.

1: Do I need MX records for the subdomain if they emails will only be going to domains registered in our Workspace.
2: If I do need the MX records for these emails to work, I've been told my multiple people to use either CloudFlare or AWS. Any others I should be looking at which allow MX records on subdomains?

I haven't tried too much yet as we just decided on the subdomain idea earlier today. I know when I did set-up the subdomain on google, it gave me an option that was something along the lines "skip MX record check", which looked like it was only supposed to be used in an advanced set-up. Would that be my fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how Google handle internal emails within its own borders, but most mail systems will aim to keep emails within their own borders when going between internal recipients. Google's mail servers will know which domains/subdomains they are responsible for, completely independent of the MX records, so if an email is going from an internal sender to an internal recipient it will likely handle it internally.

The warning about MX records is likely simply because 99% of people setting up email on there WILL want their email to work externally. Hence the advanced option you saw to skip that test.

Note, while skipping the MX record setup would prevent them from receiving email from outside of Google, I doubt it would necessarily prevent them from sending externally... though many receiving domains would reject any email from a domain without a corresponding MX record.

However, if you have a look at [Restrict email messages to authorized addresses or domains only](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2640542?hl=en) you'll see that Google do have options for specifically restricting who users can/can't email, so whether you do or don't setup the MX record, you'll likely want to have a look at those settings.

Finally, I'd ignore the comments from people suggesting you NEED to use Cloudflare/AWS for this. The only reason I can think of people would be recommending them is redundancy etc of the MX records, ensuring email MX lookups will always work... but in this scenario you don't care about that, so why pay for a service you specifically don't need. An MX record anywhere would do the job of ticking the "record exists" box.